# jquery calendar time format

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

Does anyone how to change the date format in my jquery code. By default it uses mm/dd/yy
ANd i want yy/mm/dd

Code:

```
  tjq('.datepicker-wrap input').datepicker({

        showOn: 'button',

        buttonImage: 'images/icon/blank.png',

        buttonText: '',

        buttonImageOnly: true,

        /*showOtherMonths: true,*/

        minDate: 0,

        dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {

            var themeClass = tjq(input).parent().attr("class").replace("datepicker-wrap", "");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("class", "");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(themeClass);

        }

    });
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hay you can do it like this, just add this option and read the officail docu.http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

```
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'



tjq('.datepicker-wrap input').datepicker({

        showOn: 'button',


        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

        buttonImage: 'images/icon/blank.png',

        buttonText: '',

        buttonImageOnly: true,

        /*showOtherMonths: true,*/

        minDate: 0,

        dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {

            var themeClass = tjq(input).parent().attr("class").replace("datepicker-wrap", "");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("class", "");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all");

            tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(themeClass);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default date format by sending it in when you initialize the `datepicker`. You can see an example in my snippet.  Take a look at the [jQuery API for the datepicker for more info](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Here is a [fiddle to play with as well](http://jsfiddle.net/c2a7ygvt/)

```js
$('input').datepicker({
    //showOn: 'button',
    //buttonImage: 'images/icon/blank.png',
    //buttonText: '',
    //buttonImageOnly: true,
    //showOtherMonths: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    beforeShow: function (input, inst)
    {
        //var themeClass = tjq(input).parent().attr("class").replace("datepicker-wrap", "");
        //tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("class", "");
        //tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all");
        //tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(themeClass);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input />
```